# Creating Next/Previous Navigation

Tags: jquery, pagination, navigation

I am working on a site that has multiple sections, each with around 5-10 projects within them. I am trying to create a next/previous navigation that will allow you to scroll through the projects within each section. This is the code I had for this:

```
  var prev_li     = $('.projects ul li.selected').prev('li'),
  prev_href   = $(prev_li).children().attr('href'),
  next_li     = $('.projects ul li.selected').next('li'),
  next_href   = $(next_li).children().attr('href');

$('#previous-project').click(function(e){
        if ($(prev_li).length) {
          window.location = prev_href;
          return false;
        } else {
          window.location = last_href;
          return false;
        }
  });
```

And then the same from the next project. My problem is that there are duplicate projects (some projects are in multiple sections). This means that multiple projects have the same URL and so some projects will get the class of "selected" when they really are not selected. This means that when you are on a project that is in multiple section and click the next or previous button, it will go to the previous project from the first instance of the project (even if that is in another section). I need some efficient way to specify the list of projects within each section and so it only rotates through those projects.

One idea I had was to add a class to each list of projects and do something like this:

```
  var traeng_prev_li     = $('.transportation-engineering.projects ul li.selected').prev('li'),
      traeng_prev_href   = $(traeng_prev_li).children().attr('href'),
      traeng_next_li     = $('.transportation-engineering.projects ul li.selected').next('li'),
      traeng_next_href   = $(traeng_next_li).children().attr('href');

// same variables for each section

  $('#previous-project').click(function(){
    if ($(traeng_prev_li).length) {
      window.location = traeng_prev_href;
      return false;
    } else if ($(struct_prev_li).length) {
      window.location = struct_prev_href;
      return false;
    } else if ($(civil_prev_li).length) {
      window.location = civil_prev_href;
      return false;
    } else if ($(archi_prev_li).length) {
      window.location = archi_prev_href;
      return false;
.... //all the way down through all the sections
```

The problem with this is a) it is terribly inefficient and b) I think even if you are not on that list, it still has a length and so the problem still persists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add hashes at the end of the urls that specify the section

like `/projects/poplar_street_roundabou#transportation-facilities`

then you can use the `location.hash` to target the specific section when finding next/prev

```
var prev_li = $('.projects.' + window.location.hash.substring(1) + ' ul li.selected').prev('li')
```

---

**kind of step by step explanation**

when the url has a `#transportation-facilities` (*called hash*) we can access it from javascript with the [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property.

but it will return the `#` char as well, so we need to remove it by using the [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method.

Now in jquery we need to target the `ul` that is inside an element that has the `projects` class but also the `transportation-facilities` class. In CSS this is achieved by using the [`multiple class selector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) for example `.class1.class2` will match elements that have both `class1` and `class2` assigned to them.

so this line

```
$('.projects.' + window.location.hash.substring(1) + ' ul li.selected').prev('li')
```

translates to

```
$('.projects.transportation-facilities ul li.selected').prev('li')
```

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. So, on each of the general project pages I would add the appropriate # ending to the sidebar links? Then I would change the code to be what you have above. Would this eliminate the need to repeat the code for each section? I guess I am understanding the concept, but how you've executed doesn't make much sense to me. What does the code inside $() select? How will that select the correct li?

Comment: @andrew yes, your project urls would need to have the `#<SECTION_HERE>` part added to them. I have also updated my answer with some more info..

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for your help!